# How to restrict adding Items to a SharePoint List after a particular time frame?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, access

I am using a SharePoint custom list. I need to restrict adding items to that list for all the users who is having access to the particular list.

As in, by the end of this year, all the users who has access to the list, should not be able to add items.

Can I set this automatically? Or what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Yes you can do that by adding Event receiver to that list. In which you can apply your logic to block the entries. Read this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Timer Job should work in this case, you can set the Timer Job to run daily and check if the year has ended.. Or if it's relative to the List, than you can get the list and check when it was created and if particular days have passed..

If the condition is fulfilled, you need to Break the inheritance of the list.. Or if already broken, remove the permissions of all users from the list.

Once you remove the permissions, the users will not be able to add items to the list.. If you want them to view-only, give View-Only/Read permissions accordingly.